# What does chrome show for an object iterator

Tags: javascript, object, iterator, generator

In chrome 45:

```
{}[Symbol.iterator]
//returns [Symbol(Symbol.iterator)]
typeof ({}[Symbol.iterator])
//returns "undefined"
({}[Symbol.iterator]) || "foo"
//returns "foo"
```

So object's iterator is some sort of undefined...but then what on earth is that first line showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` in your first line is a code block (with no code in it), not an object. It's then followed by an array literal containing the value of `Symbol.iterator`, which is what the console shows as the value.

When you put `(` before `{`, it becomes an object because you can't have a block of code inside parens.

Comment: Dear god! What a dumb thing.. Same thing that gets me every time I try to return an empty object from an arrow function.